# Create fixed order for integration tests in failesafe plugin

Tags: java, maven, surefire, maven-failsafe-plugin

We are using maven in combination with the maven-failsafe-plugin to run our integration tests. This works fine, but we notice that some more long running tests are started at the end. This is not optimal because all other tests are finished while this longer running tests still takes minutes to finish. It would be more efficient to start these long running tasks first.

I notice that there is an runOrder option that can optimize this, but that uses analyses data from one test run that needs to be checked in. As we use git with a lot of branches this isn't really a good option. Also tests tend to run quite long when they are failing, when normally they are quite fast, so we are afraid these optimizations won't really work for us.

What we are looking for is a way to just specify the exact order in which to run our tests. With that I mean the order of the test classes, not the methods. We have about 25 classes, so it would be totally doable just to list them in the optimal order when they should be picked up. Is there currently a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using JUnit or TestNG?

Comment: JUnit in combination with selenium and cucumber